# Why do i get no method error in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have my controller like this -

```
def show
 if authenticated_user
        render json: @authenticated_user.users_organisation.as_json(
         only: [:id, :user_id]
            ),
        status: :ok
 else
        render json: { errors: { authentication_token: 'Invalid' } },
        status: :unauthorized
```

end
end

The authenticated_user is working fine as I have tested it, Also the other table is called users_organisation.

I tried creating a user like this -

```
@user = User.where(email:"test@test.com")
```

and then I call

```
 render json: @user.users_organisation.as_json(
     only: [:id, :user_id]
        ),
    status: :ok

and then when I run it, there are no errors and it works
```

The error trace i get is -

```
 NoMethodError in Api::V1::UserTest#show
 undefined method `users_organisation' for #
<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fc59a47c798>


app/controllers/api/UserTest.rb:27:in `show'
config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb:7:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
```

Comment: Atleast say why before you downvote.

Comment: what and where's the error?

Comment: can post the complete error trace?

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy Added the error trace

Comment: what is `users_organisation`?

Comment: where you are initialising `@authenticated_user` in `show` method of `user_test_controller.rb`??

Comment: Just after the show method. I call @authenticated_user = User.where(...)

Comment: can you post `user` and `user_organisation` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@user = User.where(email:"test@test.com").first
```

The error you are getting says you are trying to access `users_organisation` on an `ActiveRecord_Relation`

Answer (score 2):

> I tried creating a user like this -
>
> ```
> @user = User.where(email:"test@test.com")
> ```

[`where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) doesn't create a user, it returns a relation. More specifically your code returns (a relation for) all users with an `email` of `"test@test.com"`, equivalent to:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'test@test.com';
```

Furthermore, that relation does not respond to `users_organisation`, so you get a `NoMethodError`.

To *create* a new user, call [`create`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-create):

```
@user = User.create(email: 'test@test.com')
#=> #<User id: 1, email: "test@test.com">
```

It returns an instance of `User` which does respond to `users_organisation`. (although it will probably be empty for a new user)

Answer (score 1):

To create a new User,

> @user = User.where(email: 'user1@example.com')
>
> @user.create

OR

> @user = User.create(email: 'user1@example.com')

As it creates new User, **ActiveRecord_Relation** for **users_organisation** may be nil. So you need to check it.